# Doctrine2 does not lazy load on one to one bidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm facing some annoying problem with doctrine 2.

I have a document entity and a conference entitiy.

```
/**
 *
 * @author klauss
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity = "Conference", mappedBy = "image")
     */
    protected $conference;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize="4M",
     *      maxSizeMessage="Allowed maximum size is {{ limit }}"
     * )
     */
    public $file;

    // .....
```

And the Conference Entity

```
// .........

    /**
     * Uploaded image.
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity = "Document", inversedBy = "conference")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name = "image", nullable = true, referencedColumnName = "id")
     */
    protected $image;

// ............
```

So in a Twig template I'd like to do the following:

```
{{ conference.image.path }}
```

But it just does not load the image, I always need to call

```
$conference->getImage()->getPath();
```

in the PHP to get the correct path in Twig. But shouldn't that be the same? If I don't call it in PHP, the Twig call just returns an empty string

How can I achieve that Doctrine automatically is aware of the Document relation?

Comment: Try `{{ conference.getImage.getPath }}` in Twig just to be sure it calls the getters as it should. You can also search in `app/dev/cache` for the offending template name (something like search for `AcmeBundle:Conference:view.html.twig`) and check the resulting template code associated with your Twig template to see how it calls your object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your entity class variables private or protected.  Doctrine 2 relies on this to work it's lazy loading magic.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/architecture.html